# No keyword with name 'Read Csv File To List' found

Tags: python, csv, robotframework

I'm automating with robot framework but I'm getting this error

```
No keyword with name 'Read Csv File To List' found
```

Here is my code:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library           CSVLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${value_to_find}    Test11

*** Test Cases ***
Test
  [Tags]  regression
    Read file and verify

*** Keywords ***
Read csv and verify
  @{list}=  Read Csv File To List    columdata.csv
  :FOR    ${x}    IN    @{list}
  \    Log  ${x}
  \    Set test variable    ${x}
  \    verify variable
  \    Run keyword if    ${status}    Log to console    found it
  \    Exit For Loop If    ${status}
  Run keyword if    not ${status}    Log to console    found it
```

I had already installed the CSVLibrary but why I got the error "No keyword with name 'Read Csv File To List' found" Can anyone help me pls I just new for Robot Framework.

Comment: Where did you get the CSVLibrary? Maybe the version you have doesn't have that keyword.

Comment: How did you install the CSVLibrary, through `pip install -U robotframework-csvlibrary` from the [robotframework-csvlibrary documentation](https://github.com/s4int/robotframework-CSVLibrary)?

Comment: I had installed csv library by pip install -U robotframework-csvlibrary and my csv library version is 0.0.3 but I still got the error "No keyword with name 'Read Csv File To List' found.".

Comment: My robot framework  version is  3.0.2

Comment: I already fixed this problem by uninstalling the csv library and install it again and move the test file to directory D, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the indentation.

There should be more space between `@{list}=` and `Read Csv...`

Comment: It already 2 spaces